# Transfer data between AWS RDS MySQL db's

Tags: heroku, amazon-web-services, mysql, amazon-rds

What is the best way to transfer data out of one amazon rds mySQL instance into another aws account's RDS mySQL instance?

This is for transferring a website on Heroku to a different owner.

Comment: Database is small a couple of GBs

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If it's that small just use the `mysqldump` utility from your mysql client.

```
#note I'm piping it through GZip for compression. It will save you bandwidth
$ mysqldump -u user --password=passowrd -h your_rds_host db_name | gzip -c > db.sql.gz

#unzip the dump
$ gunzip db.sql.gz

#restore on the destination
$ mysql -u user --password=passowrd -h your_destination_rds_host db_name < db.sql
```

That should do the trick.

Comment: Does that really save bandwidth? Wouldn't that simply perform the dump remotely, then transfer the raw SQL dump over the wire, then pipe it to gzip before writing to disk? That doesn't seem like it would reduce bandwidth/transfer size

Answer (score 2):

I sometimes use a MySQL client (Navicat) which let's you migrate data from one DB to another. It supports syncing of DB structure, data or both. Pretty handy.

Comment: agree, Navicat is really great tool.